# PHP session_cache_limiter(), session_cache_expire() and session_start()

Tags: php, session, caching

I'm using session_cache_limiter() and session_cache_expire() at the top of my PHP 5.1.0 script, just before my session_start().

From PHP help:

> [...] you need to call
>   session_cache_limiter() for every
>   request (and before session_start() is
>   called).

But **what if I don't call session_start()**? Will session_cache_limiter() and session_cache_expire() work without a session_start() after them?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Example taken straight from ["PHP: session_cache_limiter"](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-cache-limiter.php) off php.net

```
<?php
/* set the cache limiter to 'private' */
session_cache_limiter('private');
$cache_limiter = session_cache_limiter();
echo "The cache limiter is now set to $cache_limiter<br />";
?>
```

Quoted section below from original is false.  See @eCaroth's comment below for corrected information.

> <del>Also, it depends on your definition of *work*, the functions will be
>   called and will not throw an error if `session_start()` is not called,
>   but thats pointless. The purpose of those functions are for sessions
>   and in order to use sessions you need `session_start()` to be called.</del>

Comment: Does session_cache_limiter() still send headers if session_start() isn't called?

Comment: In the given example above, its value `'private'` evaluates to a specific header that is sent, I would imagine so simply on the fact that the example is used to change the header sent without calling `session_start()`

Comment: Anthony,
the function merely modifies the value of session.cache_limiter (which starts as the default value specified in the INI file at each request) and is the same as calling ini_set('session.cache_limiter','private').
The reason is has to be called before session_start() is because session_start() outputs all the headers required for the session page, INCLUDING the caching headers (which are determined by the session.cache_limiter value)

Comment: Thank you for providing some insight, that I did not know of.

Answer (score 2):

NO, ssession_cache_limiter and session_cache_expire merely modify the values php uses for session.cache_limiter and session.cache_expire (which are used when generating the session headers in session_start()) - the functions don't actually send out headers themselves, else you couldn't use them before session_start()